# Изменить количество выводимых постов при поиске

Tags: wordpress, пагинация

На сайте включена пагинация и при поиске из базы данных берётся количество постов, указанных в `"Настройки" -> "Чтение" -> "На страницах блога отображать не более"` ([скриншот](https://cdn3.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/10/6/cbca58c7130ce41bfb07d3546ea99ea9-full.png)). Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы при поиске показывалось, например, по 10 постов, а во всех остальных случаях бралось значение из настроек сайта в админке? Результаты поиска выводятся в `search.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо фильтровать основной запрос WordPress. Добавьте код в functions.php

```
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
    /**
     * Modify WordPress Search.
     *
     * @param WP_Query $query Current WordPress query.
     *
     * @return WP_Query
     */
    function my_search_filter( $query ) {
        if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search ) {
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 );
        }

        return $query;
    }

    add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_search_filter' );
}
```

Comment: То, что нужно, спасибо!